Vs code is not opening up in mac
I’ve been experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code where it won’t open at all. I’ve tried uninstalling and reinstalling it several times, but there are no changes. I’m using [your operating system].
Steps I’ve taken:
1.  Uninstalled VS Code.
2.  Deleted any remaining VS Code folders.
3.  Restarted my computer.
4.  Reinstalled VS Code.

Despite these steps, when I try to open VS Code, nothing happens. There are no error messages or any indications of what might be wrong.

You can use last working version : May 2024 (version 1.90) https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_90
until they are fixing it.

Also disable updates via "update.mode": "none" in settings till this issue is resolved.

Do you have a secondary display?

Originally I found https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81970, but it doesn't mention a solution. I have it where the pid of the process constantly changes.
Then I found https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/219893, which worked for me.
The solution was to rename the installed Visual Code and download version 1.90.

This happened to me after upgrading to MacOS Sequoia today. To fix it:
Find your VS code application > right click and Show package contents > navigate to Contents/MacOS > open Electron
This opened VS code for me. Update VS code if any new updates are available, and it works fine after that. You also don't lose your settings this way.

am still not able to open it, it gives a light black backdrop as if something will open but nothing.

I recently updated to macOS Sequoia as well. This worked for me. Thanks! After the VS Code opens, it says "Reactivating Terminal..." in the status bar, and it loads a terminal that shows it is checking for updates, downloading, and then updating. It did some updates automatically after opening the Electron. Now it's working.

Download another build:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/219893#issuecomment-2215869269
This worked for me.

I had a similar issue, VS code crashes on Launch. I renamed the installed Visual Code and downloaded version 1.90. and that resolves the issue.

If your issue is with v1.91, this issue has been resolved with v1.91.1, which "will be released in the next couple of days [from the date of this post] to stable release line" as per: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/219893#issuecomment-2216468779
But can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/219893#issuecomment-2215869269

this worked for me:
uninstall the currrent installation
go the link to download v1.90 https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_90
Install and update the setting.json: "update.mode": "none" in File > Preferences > Settings
the bad is that I lost all my settings

I had the same problem after upgrading to node 20.x and npm 10.x, before I was using version 16.x and 8.x (node/npm) I went back to these versions and the problem went away.

Had the same problem, I just restarted my computer a few times(~2-3) and ran(in total ~10 times) vscode from the electron file(see a comment from @AksMen) and it started working normally

Had the same problem after upgrading to MacOS Sequoia. I've just downloaded the latest installer from here and replaced VSCode in my Applications folder.
